# Grabbing RGB values from a colorless pictures data (PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to know if it's possible to grab an images RGB values from it's (get)data if it's colorless. I currently have a piece of code that looks like this (np=numpy):

```
Image image = Image.open(path)
n, m = image.size
data = np.array(image.getdata())
R = np.zeros(n*m, dtype=np.float)
G = np.zeros(n*m, dtype=np.float)
B = np.zeros(n*m, dtype=np.float)

for x in range (0, n*m):
    RGB = data[x]
    R[x] = RGB[0]
    G[x] = RGB[1]
    B[x] = RGB[2]
```

This lets me grab all the RGB-values. It works perfectly with color pictures, but black/white pictures crashes when it tries to set R[x]. The error:

```
indexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

This error is thrown at the line

```
R[x] = RGB[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
img = Image.open(path)
layeredimg = img.convert('RGB')
```

You do this before converting to a numpy array. You can find more info [the docs for PIL.Image](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html) (strictly speaking for Pillow, a fork of PIL).

If you want to do this condtionally(i.e. if you want to use the same code for B/W and color images) you could do it like this:

```
img = Image.open(path)
if img.layers == 1:
    img = img.convert('RGB')
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! Need to wait 8 minutes to accept.

Comment: Since you edited that in. I am using the same code for both B/W and color, but it works without the condition (e.g. it works if you always convert the image to RGB). I guess  you'll save some time by not processing the image if it's not B/W, but that's pretty miniscule, no?

Comment: Good point, img.convert() makes a copy, so it's not entirely free, but it shouldn't be a big deal.